# I managed to insert a `String` into an `ArrayList<Integer>`; why the type system did not stop me?

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? extends Object> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Object> objectList = (List<Object>) integerList;
        objectList.add("a");
        objectList.add(3);
        System.out.println(objectList);
        // [a, 3]
    }
}
```

This code compiles and runs giving:

```
[a, 3]
```

Question is how come Java allow a `String` to be inserted into an `ArrayList<Integer>` ?

I understand that `ArrayList<Integer>` is effectively just `ArrayList` at runtime (type erasure) and hence this works; but i wonder why the type system allowed this ?

---

**Notes**:

What the above code manages to do is to cast `List<Integer>` into a `List<Object>` through a two step casting like so:

```
List<Object> objectList = (List<Object>)(List<? extends Object>) integerList;
```

Interestingly, the compiler does not allow a direct cast:

```
List<Object> objectList = (List<Object>) integerList;

// compile error: incompatible types
```

Comment: Because you told it to: `(List<Object>) integerList`!

Comment: And you ignored the warning *telling* you that you were doing something unsafe: "Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations."

Comment: The situation that you created here is called [heap pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution).

Comment: *`Given: List<? extends Object> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`*  *`Interestingly, the compiler does not allow a direct cast:  e.g.  List<Object> objectList = (List<Object>) integerList;`*  Well, it works for me using a command line of `javac foo.java`   In Eclipse it provided a type safety warning. which can be suppressed.  How are you compiling it?

Comment: @WJS Yes you are right; i should have clarified that `integerList` is `List<Integer>` as opposed to `List<? extends Object>`

Comment: @JobinJacobKavalam  Please edit your question and clarify that for others who may want to understand the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Because you told the type-system:

> I know what I am doing

And then proceeded to shove a stick on your bike front wheel